# ShowCase View with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, showcaseview

I'm trying to do a intro tutorial for my android aplication that uses View Pager with Fragments Pager Adapter and the things don't work with fragments.

I'm using this library: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

```
    t1 = new ViewTarget(R.id.btnGenerate, getActivity());
    t2 = new ViewTarget(R.id.cbFavorito, getActivity());
    t3 = new ViewTarget(R.id.txtResult, getActivity());


    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                if(isAdded()) {
                showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTarget(Target.NONE)
                        .setContentTitle("Tutorial")
                        .setContentText("Aprenda como usar o aplicativo")
                        .build();
                showcaseView.setButtonText("Next");
                showcaseView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        switch (contador) {
                            case 0:
                                showcaseView.setShowcase(t1, true);
                                showcaseView.setContentTitle("Teste");
                                showcaseView.setContentText("Teste");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                showcaseView.setShowcase(t2, true);
                                showcaseView.setContentTitle("Gerar um nome");
                                showcaseView.setContentText("Teste");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                showcaseView.setShowcase(t3, true);
                                showcaseView.setContentTitle("Adicionar aos Favoritos");
                                showcaseView.setContentText("teste");
                                showcaseView.setButtonText("Fechar");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                showcaseView.hide();
                                break;
                        }
                        contador++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

In the code above I'm trying to focus different buttons when I click in button Next of ShowCase View, but, when is clicked the tutorial just closes, nothing happens, no erros, just closes.

Comment: Did you put your code in onViewCreated of the Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have take the event Listner from Button,  try this:

```
  public void run() {
                            try {
                                showCase();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

and ShowCase:

```
 showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.tool_bar, getActivity()))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title_list_os))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.dica_atualizar_os))
                .setOnClickListener(this)
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme)
                .build();
```

your activity needs Implements View.OnclickListener

Sorry my english.